# django: Admin interface for an extended class

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two classes for which I want an admin interface. But one class extends the other. Ex

```
class Questions(models.Model):
     pass

class MathQuestion(Questions):
     some fields ....
```

Now the simplest way is to create a separate admin for MathQuestion. However, is there a possibility that I can have MathQuestion displayed in a more intuitive fashio in Admin, ex: When user goes to QuestionAdmin interface and selects a further type for Maths.

Comment: If the Question model has a required field (say a slug field), then removing a MathQuestion does not remove the Question instance from database. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add extra field 'question_type' with default value of `None` and not nullable (so you can be sure Question can't have instances, not sure if it works)
2. overload the `save` method in child class and assign there some value to question_type, meaning MathQuestion.
3. Use filtering in admin as always.